# urllib2 - counting number of lines in a .csv file - python

Tags: python, csv, urllib2

How do you count the number of lines in a .csv file using urllib2?

I have the code below:

```
import urllib2
url = 'http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/' + year[2:4] + month + day + '_rpts_filtered.csv'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
file_name = csv.reader(response)
```

All I need is the length (number of lines) of that csv file. I tried:

```
length = len(response)
```

But that did practically nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within `Python2` and using `urllib2` you can do somehting like this:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen

url = 'http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/yesterday_hail.csv'
request = Request(url)
csv_len = len(urlopen(request).readlines())
print csv_len
```

Within `Python3` and using `urllib.request` you can do something like this example:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = 'http://www.spc.noaa.gov/climo/reports/yesterday_hail.csv'
request = Request(url)
csv_len = len(urlopen(request).readlines())
print(csv_len)
```

Both will output:

```
7
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
length = len(list(file_name))
```